# Doctrine 2.5 - Generate schema provider class from existing database

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, migration

#### Question

Are there any existing tools able to generate an implementation of `Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Provider\SchemaProvider` reflecting the state of an existing database?

I googled for a while and looked at similar questions in SO but i couldn't find an answer. They are all related to Symfony + Doctrine ORM.

---

#### Why do i need this?

I want to use doctrine migrations to manage/track changes on an existing database.  I cannot jump into using doctrine ORM because I would need to refactor the database and it would break other ( non php ) applications that depend on it.

---

I know i can use migrations without ORM, but i need to provide a concrete implementation of `Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Provider\SchemaProvider` ([documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/generating_migrations.html)), in my case this would mean to rewrite the entire database.

If i had the `SchemaProvider` generated for the first time to reflect the state of the database. Eg

```
<?php 

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\Provider\StubSchemaProvider;

final class MySchemaProvider implements SchemaProvider {

    public function createSchema()
    {
        $schema = new Schema();

        $table = $schema->createTable('foo');
        $table->addColumn('id', 'integer', array(
            'autoincrement' => true,
        ));
        $table->setPrimaryKey(array('id'));

        //and so on for the rest of the databse... 

        return $schema;
    }  

}
```

I would be able to edit the generated class and create migrations with:

```
$ ./doctrine migrations:diff
```

Comment: You could reverse engineer a database and create the entities http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Comment: This was my first choice, sadly the "mapped" version is different from the original. I used those tools to map/generate the entities, than created an empty database ( `php bin/console doctrine:schema:create` ), once the schema was created i compared it's DDL with the original one and what i saw was: Foreign keys constraints changed ( actions where not exported ), all `UNSIGNED INT` fields where exported as `INT`, I had to manually add the `fulltext` flag on indexes because they were not exported either. The problem i see here is that if i miss anything i will break other applications.